# Is it possible to query dictionary on parse.com?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

i’m trying to search dictionary match result but no luck

my parse dictionary column look like this

columnName: Tag property: object

{"firstKey”:”David”,”secondKey”:”Guetta”}

columnName: name property: string

cool
￼￼￼￼￼￼

when I try to search name column

here is my code snippet,

```
static func parseQueryDictionary()  {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"TestDictionary")
    query.whereKey("name", equalTo: "cool")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil {
            print("objects is", objects)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

i get result below

objects is Optional([ {
    Tag =     {
        firstKey = David;
        secondKey = Guetta;
    };
    name = cool;
    tagArray =     (
        David,
        Guetta
    );
}])

i've try array column 
columnName: tagArray property: array
["David","Guetta"]

```
static func parseQueryDictionary()  {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"TestDictionary")
    query.whereKey("tagArray", equalTo:"David")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil {
            print("objects is", objects)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

i get result

objects is Optional([ {
    Tag =     {
        firstKey = David;
        secondKey = Guetta;
    };
    name = cool;
    tagArray =     (
        David,
        Guetta
    );
}])

but when i try to search dictionary column

columnName: Tag property: object
{"firstKey”:”David”,”secondKey”:”Guetta”}

like this

```
static func parseQueryDictionary()  {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"TestDictionary")
    query.whereKey("Tag", equalTo:"David")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil {
            print("objects is", objects)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

i get no result

objects is Optional([])

￼

i’ve try google and parse official doc but can’t find this case, is it possible to do that?

i've try search string column, array column it's work but only dictionary column not work...

Comment: key should be column name in parse .Of Course you can do it

Comment: @cool I hope you are aware that parse is shutting down on January 2017.

Answer (score 0):

search in google with "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" in swift.It will give you many results.

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: parseClassName)
            query.whereKey("Position", equalTo: "iOS Developer")//Here Position is column name and Sales Manager is value.
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
                if(error == nil){
                    for object in objects {

                    }

                }
                else{
                    println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
                }

            })
```